# Disk Scheduling SSTF in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a demo about Disk Scheduling - SSTF in Javascript but 
when I run, the console keeps running but doesn't show result or error for a very long time. I guess my code is wrong somewhere but I cannot figure it out.
Can you guys help me? Thank you very much!
Sorry for my bad Eng!

```js
var arr = [53, 98, 183, 37, 122, 14, 124, 65, 67];

//shortest seek time first
function sstf(arr) {

    var headFirst = arr[0];
    arr.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b });
    var headStart = 0;
    var headMove = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == headFirst) {
            headStart = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    while (true) {
        //
        if (headStart === 1 || headStart === arr.length) {
            break;
        }

        //define local a, b which are the distance between the next and the previous of the current index
        if (arr[headStart - 1] === "undefined") {
            a = arr[headStart] - arr[headStart];
        } else {
            a = arr[headStart] - arr[headStart - 1];
        }
        if (arr[headStart + 1] === "undefined") {
            b = arr[headStart] - arr[headStart];
        } else {
            b = arr[headStart + 1] - arr[headStart];
        }

        //compare a & b
        if (a < b) {
            headMove += a;
            var temp = headStart;
            arr.splice(headStart, 1);
            headStart = temp - 1;
        } else if (a > b) {
            headMove += b;
        }
    }

    //check if headStart = at the beginning going forward or at the last going backward
    if (headStart === 1) {
        for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            headMove += Math.abs(arr[i] - arr[i - 1]);
        }
    } else if (headStart === arr.length) {
        for (var i = arr.length - 1; i > 1; i--) {
            headMove += Math.abs(arr[i - 1] - arr[i])
        }
    }

    return headMove;
}
console.log(sstf(arr));
```

Comment: Remove the `while(true)` loop while debugging and add some break points to inspect the variables on each iteration. You will find that `a` and `b` never change. `a > b` is always true, so only `headMove` updates each iteration. Your code will loop until you run out of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that js index start from 0, not 1. So you have to change some "1" to "0" in your code.

```
if (a > b) {
    headMove += b;
}
```

should be

```
if (a > b) {
    headMove += b;
    arr.splice(headStart, 1);
}
```

to remove current value to correctly perform the check at the start of while block.

The main cause make your code running forever is you doesn't remove item in "arr" as I said above. Then the headStart still stuck somewhere and the "break" never happen.

Comment: Simply not true

Comment: Could you explain why you say that? It doesn't good when rate down without reason!

Comment: Index starts at 0 in JS

Comment: "Keep in mind that js index start from 0, not 1." what wrong with this sentence? https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp said that "[0] is the first element in an array. [1] is the second. Array indexes start with 0."

Comment: My mind, sorry I just read it vice versa. Anyway, as you can see in his code, he does index it with 0, that's what cause my confusion. E.g. for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {